# Delete elements of list with certain length

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list containing some other lists having different lengths. I want to remove some of the lists with a certain length. For example, I have

```
a = {{0, 5, 2, 15, 6, 9, 3}, {1}, {5, 5, 5}, {4, 4, 5, 6}, {5}};
```

I want to remove some sub-lists of `a` having length 1. I mean, I want the result to be as

```
{{0, 5, 2, 15, 6, 9, 3}, {5, 5, 5}, {4, 4, 5, 6}}
```

How can I do that using Mathematica?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select[a, Length@# != 1 &]
```

> {{0, 5, 2, 15, 6, 9, 3}, {5, 5, 5}, {4, 4, 5, 6}}

Also

```
GeneralUtilities`Discard[a, Length[#] == 1 &]
```

> {{0, 5, 2, 15, 6, 9, 3}, {5, 5, 5}, {4, 4, 5, 6}}

and

```
DeleteCases[a, _?(Length@# == 1 &)]
```

> {{0, 5, 2, 15, 6, 9, 3}, {5, 5, 5}, {4, 4, 5, 6}}

Answer (score 6):

This might be faster than klgr's solutions on large lists:

```
Pick[a, Unitize[Length /@ a - 1], 1]
```

`Select` and `DeleteCases` are known to be kind of slow.